# PHP / Curl - file_get_contents / Slow when retrieving local content

Tags: php, curl

I have a 4G modem attached to a Raspberry and I'm trying to query the modem API to retrieve the signal strength. The modem API can be reached by something like this: http://192.168.8.1/api/device/signal

When I visit this url from the raspberry with a browser, I get an immediate/fast response.
The Raspberry is not connected to Internet, I can only access it from local network (with local ip).

If I use cUrl or file_get_content from the Raspberry itself, it takes at least 30-40 seconds to get the results.

Example:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://192.168.8.1/api/device/signal");
```

or this:

```
$headers = array("Host: www.blabla.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.8.1/api/device/signal");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);  
echo $output;
```

Both scripts return the information I'm looking for but I don't understand why both scripts take so long while the API is really fast. Is there something I should change in my PHP.ini ? Or something else?

Any idea?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to curl the endpoint from the terminal to see how it behaves there?

Comment: yes, it is the same.